Singular or plural with "as well as"
Which is the correct sentence?
This thing, as well as those other things, has improved over time.
This thing, as well as those other things, have improved over time.

The subject is "This thing" which is singular. Or you could say "All these things have improved over time."

@WeatherVane thanks - so the following would be correct? Technology, as well as the arts and sciences, has improved over time? (Why is it jarring to my ear?)

I suggest it seems to jar because you try to match the verb to the most recent noun, instead of the subject of the verb.

@EdwinAshworth you are correct. Should I delete this question?

Note that better answers are given by Barrie England, Shoe and Robusto at singular or plural verb form where subject includes a parenthetical element.
